# SQL Server string comparison fails

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, jpa

We have this issue on SQL Server (2019 SE and 2022 EE):

```
select 
    case 
        when '8AA' < '8E2' then 1
        when '8AA' > '8E2' then -1
        when '8AA' = '8E2' then 0
    end as ok
```

-1 (incorrect)

```
select
    case
        when '8BA' < '8E2' then 1
        when '8BA' > '8E2' then -1
        when '8BA' = '8E2' then 0
    end as ok
```

1 (correct)

So, when comparing two strings we seem to have found an error as one would expect '8AA' to come before 'BE2'.
In the other example we have only substituted an 'A' for a 'B' in the first string. It should still come before the right-hand-side of the comparison. And it does.

When removing the number and the last 'A' (from the original query), we get:

```
select  
    case  
        when '8A' < '8E' then 1
        when '8A' > '8E' then -1
        when '8A' = '8E' then 0
    end as ok
```

1 (correct)

Which suggests that not only is the sorting wrong, but it is triggered by the third digit - even though the comparison should already have "concluded" after the second character.

Any one seen this before? Know what it is about?

Final note: we have found this issue when doing some stuff in Java via Spring/JPA. The ordering in Java is consistent - or as one would expect - and the error then occurs as SQL Server apparently has an issue. In other words: in this (admittedly, edge-) case Java string comparison and SQL server ditto do not agree.

Tried:

```
select  
    case
        when '8AA' < '8E2' then 1
        when '8AA' > '8E2' then -1 
        when '8AA' = '8E2' then 0
    end as ok
```

Got "-1".

Expected "1"

Comment: AA in Danish Collation is not "sorted" as normal AA so that's the reason

Comment: Btw. we tried the exact same thing on IBM Netezza and got the correct result (so Netezza and MS SQL do not agree and Netezza seems to be right)

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot - we should have seen that one. Thanks a lot :) Please add an answer so we can give it the right credits

Comment: You can upvote the duplicate question :)